# Ruby undefined method `getBakiye' for []:Array (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby, rubygems

why i cant pass getBakiye() func of Musteri class as parametre to bakiyeBilgisi() func of Banka class ? I googled it a couple time but i didnt
something to do.i did same thing python and it worked what is different between of ruby and python at this point ? Have a good day guys

and i got this problem :

rb:122:in `bakiyeBilgisi': undefined method`getBakiye' for []:Array (NoMethodError)

```
    class Musteri
  attr_accessor :isim,:soyisim,:idno,:parola
  def initialize(isim,soyisim,idno,parola)
    @isim = isim
    @soyisim = soyisim
    @idno = idno.to_s
    @parola = parola.to_s
    @bakiye = 0
  end  
  #=====================================
  def getIsım #isim döndür
    return @isim
  end

  def getSoyIsım #soyisim al
    return @soyisim
  end

  def getIdNo #Idno al
    return getIdNo
  end

  def getParola  #parola al
    return @parola
  end

  def getBakiye  #bakiye al
    return @bakiye
  end

  def setBakiye(miktar) #bakiye değiştir
    @bakiye =miktar
    return @bakiye
  end

end #musteri sinifi bitişi

class Banka
  attr_accessor :musteriler,:isim
  def initialize(isim)
    @isim = isim
    @musteriler = []
  end #yapici    

  def musteriVarmi(idno,parola)
    for musteri in musteriler
      if musteri.getIdNo == idno and musteri.getParola == parola
        return musteri

      end 

    end 

  end 

  def aliciVarmi(idno)
    for musteri in @musteriler
      if musteri.getIdNo == idno
        return musteri
      end #if blogunun

    end #aliciVarmi for dongusu

  end #aliciVarmi fonksiyonu


  def paraAktar(gonderen,alici,miktar)
    if @musteriler.include? gonderen and @musteriler.include? alici
      if gonderen.getBakiye >= miktar
        alici.setBakiye(alici.getBakiye + miktar)
        puts "Gönderilme işlemi başarıyla gerçekleşti"
      else
        puts "Bakiye Yetersiz"
      end #paraAktar ifS
    else
      puts "Alıcı Bulunamadı"
    end #paraAktar ifS

  end #paraAktar fonk

  def musteriOl(isim,soyisim,idno,parola)
    @musteriler<<(Musteri(isim,soyisim,idno,parola))
  end #musteriOl fonk

  def paraCek(musteri,miktar)
    if miktar % 10 != 0
      puts "Bozuk para atmayiniz"
    else
      if musteri.getBakiye >= miktar
        puts "Önce paranizi\nSOnra kartinizi aliniz"
        musteri.setBakiye(musteri.getBakiye + miktar)
      else
        puts "Bakiye yetersiz"
      end #paracek elseS   
    end #paracek ifS  
  end #paracek fonk    

  def paraYatir(musteri,miktar)
    if miktar % 5 != 0
      puts "Bozuk para atmayiniz"
    else
      musteri.setBakiye(musteri.getBakiye + miktar)
      puts "Paraniz Yatirildi"
    end #paraYatir ifS
  end #paraYatir fonk

  def bakiyeBilgisi(musteri)
    musteri.getBakiye    

  end #bakiyeBİlgisi fonk    
end # Banka sinifi bitisi


def main
  banka = Banka.new("UmutPalabiyik")
  while true
    system("cls")
    puts "[1] Musteri Ol : "
    puts "[2] Giriş Yap"

    puts "Lutfen yapmak istediginiz islemi seciniz"
    secim1 = gets.chomp()

    if secim1 == "1"
      puts "Lütfen isminizi giriniz  : "
      isim = gets.chomp.to_s

      puts "Lütfen soyisminizi giriniz : "
      soyisim = gets.chomp.to_s

      puts "Lütfen id numaranizi giriniz : "
      idno = gets.chomp.to_s

      puts "Lütfen parolanızı giriniz : "
      parola = gets.chomp.to_s


      puts "Ana menuye donmek icin herhangi bir tusa basiniz"
      gets.chomp()

    elsif secim1 == "2"
      puts "Lütfen id numaranizi giriniz :"
      idno = gets.chomp.to_s

      puts "Lütfen parolanizi giriniz  :"
      parola = gets.chomp.to_s

      if banka.musteriVarmi(idno,parola)
        musteri = banka.musteriVarmi(idno,parola)
        while true
          system("cls")
          puts "[1] Bakiye Goster       [2] Para Yatır"
          puts "[3] Para Çek        [4] Para Aktar"
          puts "    [Q] Cikis"

          puts "Yapmak istediginiz islemi seciniz"
          secim2 = gets.chomp()

          if secim2 == "1"
            banka.bakiyeBilgisi(musteri)
            puts "Ana menüye dönmek için 'enter' a basiniz !"
            gets.chomp()

          elsif secim2 == "2"
            puts "Lutfen yatırmak istediginz tutari seciniz : "
            miktar = gets.chomp.to_i
            banka.paraYatir(musteri,miktar)

            puts "Ana menüye dönmek için 'enter' a basiniz !"
            gets.chomp()    

          elsif secim2 == "3"
            puts "Lütfen çekmek istediginiz miktarı giriniz : "
            miktar = gets.chomp.to_i
            banka.paraCek(musteri,miktar)

            puts "Ana menüye dönmek için 'enter' a basiniz !"
            gets.chomp()

          elsif secim2 == "4"
            puts "Alıcı ID :"
            idno = gets.chomp()

            puts "Aktarmak istediğiniz miktarı giriniz  :"
            miktar = gets.chomp().to_f

            if banka.aliciVarmi(idno)
              banka.paraAktar(musteri,banka.aliciVarmi(idno),miktar)
            else
              puts "Alici Bulunamadi !"

            end #3.elsif ifS

          elsif secim2 == "q" and secim2 == "Q"
            puts "Ana menüye yönlendiriliyorsunuz"
            sleep(0.5)
            puts "."
            sleep(0.5)
            puts ".."
            sleep(0.5)
            puts "..."
            break

          else
            puts "Hatalı Giriş"
            puts "Ana menüye dönmek için herhangi bir tusa basiniz : "
            gets.chomp()

          end # 2. while true ifS

        end #ikinci while true

      else
        puts "Banka kaydi bulunamadi ya da hatali giris"    

      end #elsif in ifS
    else
      puts "Hatali Giris"

    end #ilk ifS   
  end #while true    
end #main fonk

main
```

Comment: Your question has serious issues. Please take a tour [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking questions.

Comment: now is it good ?

Comment: Please paste your code here as a text.

Comment: How to reproduce what values should a user enter into a console. What expected output?

Comment: Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" and all their linked pages.

Comment: In Ruby variables and method names are snake_case, not camelCase. ItIsAReadabilityThing. Pay attention to that if you every intend to program as part of a team as they'll call you out in a code review. I'd recommend read https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide several times, until you understand why we do those things.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the error caused by `musteriVarmi` method. You use `for` loop to find a single value. When there aren't any matches the array `musteriler` gets returned from `musteriVarmi`. Ruby has a lot of nice methods to work with [arrays](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Enumerable.html).

```
# This code will return a found value or `nil`
def musteriVarmi(idno, parola)
  musteriler.find do |musteri|
    musteri.getIdNo == idno and musteri.getParola == parola
  end
end
```

Also, please install and check your code via [Rubocop](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/rubocop). Your code style is not conventional. And better to name classes, methods and variables in English.

Comment: Please read "[How do I write a good answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)", especially the part about well-asked questions.